# Mark checkbox "completed" in Google Docs checklist using keyboard

Tags: google-docs

I see that the checkboxes in Google Docs' checklists can be marked completed by clicking with a mouse. Is there a way for me to mark them completed using only the keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no native solution.

If you aren't using the inbuild google doc checklists you can add substitutions as a workaround. They won't have the google doc checklist functionality but you could add shortcuts for both checked and unchecked boxes.

Tools -> preferences -> substitutions

[image: Google-Docs-Substitutions-]